# How to Check $http.post() query result using POSTMAN

Tags: angularjs, rest-client, postman

I have $http.post request and it works fine.

```
$http.post("api/orders/", $scope.order).success(function(data) {

}
```

Where

```
$scope.order = {
            "order_id": "14",
            "user_id": "10",
            "amount":"400"

        };
```

How can I check the same request using postman?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the service locally, set the url to :

```
http://localhost/api/orders
```

If its not running locally, change localhost to your server name

Then set the method to POST

click on "form data" which allows you to submit key value pairs

then enter your keys and values as per your scope.order object

Comment: I tried, but it is not working. It identifies the function addOrder()

Comment: Can you please let me know what you mean when you say is is "not working" also, is this a public service? Can I try it?